How to annotate after group by and order_by in django?
I have a DB table which has a field "created_at". This is a auto_now_add=True field.
This table is inserted data once everyday. What I want to do is filter data that corresponds to the last day of each month of each year.
I have a query as follows:
qs = (
    self.model.objects().with_months()
    .with_years()
    .values('year', 'month')
    .annotate(last_day=Max('created_at'))
    .order_by('year', 'month')
    )

with_months() and with_years() methods are queryset methods that annotate year and month.
What I want to do is to annotate other fields of this model in this queryset; however, since values() returns a list of dictionaries, I am not able to do that. I cannot add other fields inside values() as they won't be grouped.
How can I achieve this?

So to achieve what you want, you can modify your query by first getting the last record for each month and year, and then performing a subquery to get the other fields from the model. You can use your existing query to get the last created_at date for each month and year. And then you have the last day of each month and year, you can use a subquery to filter the original queryset to include only those records.
from django.db.models import Max, Subquery, OuterRef
qs_last_day = (
     self.model.objects.with_months().
     with_years().
     values('year', 'month').
     annotate(last_day=Max('created_at')).
     order_by('year', 'month')
)
qs = self.model.objects.all()
subquery = qs.filter(
    created_at__date=Subquery(
        qs_last_day.filter(
            year=OuterRef('year'),
            month=OuterRef('month')
        ).values('last_day')[:1]
    ))
result = subquery.annotate(
    some_field=F('some_field'),
    another_field=F('another_field')
)

And yes ofcourse you have to change field names. This way, you get the queryset filtered by the last day of each month and year, and you can still annotate other fields of the model.
